# Asymptotic notations

Tags: asymptotics

Iv'e been given this question:
let $f,g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be **increasing monotonic** functions.
Is it always true that $f\left( n\right) =\Omega ( g\left( n\right) )$ or $g\left( n\right) =\Omega ( f\left( n\right) )$ ?
I can give a counter example only when one of the functions is not increasing monotonic, but I couldn't find a counter example for which both $f, g$ are increasing monotonic.
On the other hand, I couldn't prove that it is true.
Would like to hear any suggestions

Comment: It's not true but it's pretty annoying to write down a counterexample explicitly. The idea is that you can alternate regions where $f(n)$ increases much faster than $g(n)$ with regions where $g(n)$ increases much faster than $f(n)$, in such a way that they technically stay strictly increasing the whole time but $f(n)$ spends some time arbitrarily larger than $g(n)$ and vice versa.

Comment: What is the meaning of that $\Omega$ notation? Is it like Landau's $O$ notation?

Comment: Does $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$ mean $f(n)\geq C\cdot g(n)$ infinitely often?

Comment: @Clayton yes, it is

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan can you give an example on how to build this functions?

Comment: @Clayton It isn't "infinitely often." Rather it is "for all sufficiently large $n$."

Comment: @angryavian
 There are various non-equivalent definitions for $\Omega$ but according to himself, Tom chose [Hardy–Littlewood's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_definition), which *is* "infinitely often".

Comment: @AnneBauval My mistake, I was not aware of the Hardy-Littlewood definition. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Upon further reflection, I wonder if OP is really using the Landau definition, given that (a) they found a counterexample without the monotonicity constraint, and (b) the question is almost trivial under the Hardy-Littlewood definition (via Anne Buval's answer). Tom, could you double-confirm which definition you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\neg[f(n)=\Omega(g(n))]\Leftrightarrow f(n)=o(g(n)),$ we cannot have both $\neg[f(n)=\Omega(g(n))]$ and $\neg[g(n)=\Omega(f(n))].$ Hence the answer is: yes, it is always true that $f\left( n\right) =\Omega ( g\left( n\right) )$ or $g\left( n\right) =\Omega ( f\left( n\right) ).$

Comment: @TomWaller I must have missed something, since you mention you can give a counter example when one of the functions is not increasing monotonic. What is that counterexample?

Comment: I don't think the first equivalence stated in your answer is true.

Comment: @angryavian it depends on the definition you choose for $\Omega,$ but with
[Hardy–Littlewood's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#The_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_definition) (the one chosen by Tom), it is true.